# Is it safe to log concurrently from different processes without a lock?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I have a code like the following, which is run by many processes concurrently. The logger is configured to write to stdout only. However, if I remove the lock everything still works fine. So I wonder which approach (lock/no lock) is correct and why.

```
 self._console = logging.getLogger("console")
 with self._stdout_lock: # the line in question
            message_f = "..."
            self._console.info(message_f)
```

I've tried to replace some of loggers to raw `sys.stdout.write() sys.stdout.flush()` and it still worked fine.

Comment: I believe your question is [answered in the `multiprocessing` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes): _"...one can use a lock to ensure that only one process prints to standard output at a time...Without using the lock output from the different processes is liable to get all mixed up."_

Comment: It does not answer completely: we should imply it is safe and will not cause other problems, but strictly speaking it is not said

Comment: It is also not clear what 'mixing' up includes (can data be lost?)